# Story similar to "The Power," but all young people (not just women) develop sonic power that hurts adults

Tags: story-identification

I recall reading a summary of a story with a premise that seems similar to [*The Power*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_(Alderman_novel)), except instead of women developing electrical powers, it was children or young teens developing a yell or scream that let them incapacitate or injure adults.

Recollections (not 100% sure of any):

- Maybe from a sci-fi publisher's email newsletter (I only subscribe to the Tor.com newsletter, but I couldn't find it in my old mail or their archives); it could have been from an online article.
- Probably with the past 5-10 years
- The power manifested en masse, very rapidly (societal disruption theme)
- Presented as a sonic ability, not psychic
- The young people were immune to the effects of the ability
- There was a description or excerpt of a scene where a group of children use their power to (capriciously?) attack and take down an adult

Since it was a summary, I don't know if it was a short story, web story, novel, etc. Intergenerational conflict seems to have been the main theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you read one of the [numerous articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+Flame+Alphabet+by+Ben+Marcus) about Ben Marcus' [*The Flame Alphabet*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1575638) (2012) that accompanied its release.

In the story the speech of young people suddenly becomes somehow toxic to adults, which some of the children then turn against adults, even or especially their parents.

Quoting from an [excerpt published by Penguin Random House](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.ca/books/204524/the-flame-alphabet-by-ben-marcus/9780307739971/excerpt):

> By early December we huddled at home, speechless. If we spoke it was through faces gripped in early rigor mortis. Our neighborhood had gone blank, killed down by winter. It was too cold even for the remaining **children to do much hunting.**
>
> I don't know how else to refer to their work, but **sometimes they swarmed the block, flooding houses with speech until the adults were repulsed to the woods.**
>
> You'd see a neighbor with a rifle and you'd hear that rifle go off. The trees stood bloodless, barely holding on in the wind. We sat against the window and waited, spying out at the children when they roved through. **The children—they should have been called something else—barking toxic vocals through megaphones** as they held hands in the street.

The [blurb on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/11325011) describes it:

> A terrible epidemic has struck the country and ***the sound of children's speech has become lethal**. Radio transmissions from strange sources indicate that people are going into hiding. All Sam and Claire need to do is look around the neighborhood: In the park, **parents wither beneath the powerful screams of their children**. At night, suburban side streets become routes of shameful escape for fathers trying to get outside the radius of affliction.
>
> With Claire nearing collapse, it seems their only means of survival is to flee from their daughter, Esther, who laughs at her parents' sickness, unaware that in just a few years she, too, will be susceptible to the language toxicity. But Sam and Claire find it isn't so easy to leave the daughter they still love, even as they waste away from her malevolent speech. On the eve of their departure, Claire mysteriously disappears, and Sam, determined to find a cure for this new toxic language, presses on alone into a world beyond recognition.

Comment: (I haven't read this, nor shall I.  When I first heard about it, I thought it was some pretentious English lit take on SF themes, and having slogged through a bunch of reviews for quotes and background material that impression is only further reinforced.)

Comment: This is almost certainly it; I searched the Tor.com archives for "Flame Alphabet" and found this blog article https://www.tor.com/2012/02/08/genre-in-the-mainstream-ben-marcus-burns-down-reality-with-the-flame-alphabet/ , which contains the following: "In the first half of the novel, there are actually gangs of them roving around the neighborhood attacking people with language. Check out this chilling passage: [passage omitted due to character limits]"

Answer (score 1):

Possibly  "A Coming of Age" by Timothy Zahn

(from my notes) A planet where all children have strong telekinetic powers, which disappear at puberty. To keep control, children are brought up communally and not permitted any learning / reading, etc.

Comment: This doesn't really fit at all; the kids had psychic (telekinetic) powers, not harmful sonic powers.